# How to add or set a facesMessage inside an ejb project

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, jboss7.x

I have an ear project with war and ejb. Using omnifaces, I normally set the error message in the war project. But on one project I'm using picketlink for authentication, and unfortunately I need to move my @Picketlink annotated class inside the ejb, otherwise it won't work.

Then my authentication classes are also in the ejb project, then the problem when the user enter a wrong credential I need to show a localized error. How do I do that in the ejb project?

Or is there a way to make picketlink work moving the authentication classes back to the war project.

Sample codes:
Authentication class:

```
@PicketLink
public class PicketlinkAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator { }
```

JBoss deployment file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>

    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

    <sub-deployment name="my-project-web.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.picketlink" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not supposed to have access to JSF/Servlet artifacts such as `FacesContext` and `ServletRequest` in an EJB. So the answer would be figuring to do the job in WAR instead. I don't do PicketLink, so I can't go in detail with this, but if you reframe the question and tell more about the symptoms related to "won't work", then PicketLink users may be able to answer this.

Comment: Hi Balus, thanks for the tip. I've found a solution though it's not really the one I want. I'll add a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found 2 solutions with my problem:

1.) Move the authentication classes (picketlink) to the web layer, so that the message can be set and localized.

2.) Implement a JPA IDMConfiguration in the ejb layer. And an authentication class in the web layer.
Refer to this project from github: picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa. In this way we've created a picketlink resource that we will use in web layer authentication.